# Strength of PBKDF based AES key

Tags: c, security, encryption, cryptography, openssl

Here is a stub of a system which would generate a key pair using AES 256 CBC in OpenSSL. The object of the code below is to generate two random passkeys, an AES key, and some other public data. The AES key would be used to exchange shared secrets.

Disclaimer: I am NOT an expert in Cryptography or Security Systems. I do realize the dangers but the point of this exercise is an academic interest. If there are novice errors or something entirely and dangerously incorrect, please do point it out to aid my learning.

```
// The key_generator() will produce the following public keys in addition
// to a couple of other private keys.
// public_identifier
// public_salt
// public_composite_identifier
// public_aes_key

int key_generator(/*some args*/)
{
    // Step 1
    //Obtain public_identifier. Possibly a hashed value of an unique ASCII string.
    unsigned char *public_identifier;


    // Step 2
    //Generate 256 bit private_primary_random_passkey which is secret. 
    //This random key is generated once and reused later.
    unsigned char *private_primary_random_passkey;

    if(RAND_bytes(private_primary_random_passkey, 256) == 0)     
        return FAILURE;


    // Step 3
    //Generate private_composite_identifier using public_identifier
    //and private_primary_random_passkey.
    //IMPORTANT - The method to obtain private_composite_identifier 
    //may be publicly known.  
    //The public_identifier is also publicly known but the 
    //private_primary_random_passkey is secret.
    unsigned char *private_composite_identifier;

    //<Some code for generating private_composite_identifier>
    //.....
    //</code>


    // Step 4     
    //Generate temporary temp_private_aes_key and temp_private_aes_IV;
    //NOTE - Used dummy vars wherever key length is required. 
    //Assume correct length is passed in.

    int aes_rounds = 25000;

    unsigned char *temp_private_aes_key;
    unsigned char *temp_private_aes_IV;

    if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), 
                      EVP_sha512(), 
                      private_composite_identifier, 
                      private_primary_random_passkey, 
                      private_composite_identifier_length/8, 
                      aes_rounds, 
                      temp_private_aes_key, 
                      temp_private_aes_IV) == 0)     
        return FAILURE;    


    // Step 5
    //Generate 128 bit random salt which is public.
    unsigned char *public_salt;

    if(RAND_bytes(public_salt, 128) == 0)     
        return FAILURE;


    // Step 6
    //Generate private_composite_identifier and public_composite_identifier 
    //using temp_private_aes_key and public_salt.
    unsigned char *public_composite_identifier;
    unsigned char *private_composite_identifier;

    if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), 
                      EVP_sha512(), 
                      temp_private_aes_key,
                      public_salt,
                      temp_private_aes_key_length/8, 
                      aes_rounds, 
                      private_composite_identifier, 
                      public_composite_identifier) == 0)     
        return FAILURE;    


    // Step 7
    //Generate 128 bit private_secondary_random_passkey which is secret. 
    //This random key is generated once and reused later.
    unsigned char *private_secondary_random_passkey;

    if(RAND_bytes(private_secondary_random_passkey, 128) == 0)     
        return FAILURE;

    unsigned char *private_aes_key;
    unsigned char *public_aes_key;

    if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), 
                      EVP_sha512(), 
                      private_composite_identifier,
                      private_secondary_random_passkey,
                      private_composite_identifier_length/8, 
                      aes_rounds, 
                      private_aes_key, 
                     public_aes_key) == 0)     
        return FAILURE
}
```

Here are my questions:

- Should an RSA key pair be used instead of the AES key? Why would one be preferred over the other?
- Since the keys used to produce the key pair are long, randomly generated and salted, is it safe to use the same AES/RSA key pair later? I understand the risks of Rainbow tables and other measures but aren't those concerns alleviated with the random salts and keys followed by three levels of key generation?
- What are the ways in which a malicious attacker can recreate the key pair or break this system using the publicly available data?
- Any other points that you can think of to thwart or enhance this system.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: AES is symmetric. RSA is asymmetric.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Thanks for pointing out the n00b error. :) Could you reconsider the questions if in step 7 we generate an RSA key pair from the information available until that point and use this key pair for future encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really into Cryptography Engineering, and the folks on [Crypto Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) would probably be better suited for these sorts of design questions.

Also, you lack a lot of details for any kind of useful replies. (Come back when the question are more implementation oriented and specific).

---

> Strength of PBKDF based AES key

First, the title.

This problem is only as hard as guessing the password, and likely easier with things like multi-million word lists from past data breaches. That is, you attacker will not try to break the AES key - he or she will attempt to guess the password you used to derive the key.

To key an AES-128 key with 128-bits of security, you need 128-bits of entropy in the password. Passwords are not random and english has about 1.3 bits of entropy per letter, so expect to use about a 14+ character password for AES-128. Use a 28+ character password if you are keying AES-256.

---

> The object of the code below is to generate two random passkeys, an AES key, and some other public data. The AES key would be used to exchange shared secrets.

What is the goal here? To create a secure channel? Or just exchange keys?

Typically you use public key to transport or agreement to transport symmetric or session keys. That is: (1) use Diffie-Hellman to generate a shared secret ('key agreement' since both parties add to the process), then transport symmetric session keys under the shared secret; or (2) use RSA to transport a 'master' symmetric session key ('key transport' since one party generates the secret, encrypts it under the peer's RSA key, and then sends it to the peer).

There are Authenticated Key Exchanges based on shared secrets and passwords. SSL/TLS has two of them - Preshared Key (PSK) and Secure Remote Password (SRP). PSK uses AES as a primitive, and SRP uses Diffie-Hellman.

PSK and SRP are usually better than DH and RSA because they provide (1) mutual authentication and (2) channel binding. Based on your statement "the AES key would be used to exchange shared secrets", PSK may be perfect for you. But its not apparent if they are a good choice because we don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

---

> Should an RSA key pair be used instead of the AES key? Why would one be preferred over the other?

It depends on your problem domain and what you are trying to do.

If the server has a public RSA key, then you would use Diffie-Hellman or RSA. If you and the server share a secret, then avoid the public key stuff and use PSK or SRP.

Diffie-Hellman and RSA are expensive in terms of computation. They are usually used to exchange or transport a symmetric cipher key. RSA-2048 may take 4 or 5 million instructions, and it cripples performance.

Symmetric ciphers are fast in terms of computation. They are used for the majority of traffic once 
Diffie-Hellman or RSA is complete. We call it bulk encryption and they are fats. If you have Ivy Bridge hardware, then AES-NI can approach 1 cycle/byte for encrypted data.

When you read web servers like nginx can only handle 1000 SSL/TLS connections, you are seeing the effects of Diffie-Hellman and RSA. Once those channels are setup and keyed for bulk encryption, it can handle thousands of encrypted traffic streams.

> is it safe to use the same AES/RSA key pair later?

These are apples and oranges. You usually use a RSA key pair for long term, while AES keys are limited to a session.

In general, each run of a protocol should use different parameters. The protocol should also *lack* symmetry so that an attacker cannot start a second instance of your protocol, and then have your server answer questions present on the first instance with the second instance.

---

> I understand the risks of Rainbow tables and other measures but aren't those concerns alleviated with the random salts and keys followed by three levels of key generation?

It depends on your problem domain and what you are trying to do. We can't really answer because we don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

See John Steven's [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) at OWASP. He takes you through the threat models and explains the pieces of the system. The detailed treatment is available at [Secure Password Storage](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g).

---

> What are the ways in which a malicious attacker can recreate the key pair or break this system using the publicly available data?

It depends on your problem domain and what you are trying to do. We can't really answer because we don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Key management is the hardest part of cryptography, and all we see is a vacuum:

```
int key_generator(/*some args*/)
```

You'd need to fully detail all the parameters, how you manage them, and how you use them.

---

> Any other points that you can think of to thwart or enhance this system.

This jumps out: three calls to `RAND_byes` and `EVP_BytesToKey`. Typically, you do this:

```
byte[] master = Random(16) // or 32, or however many you need
byte[] key1 = Derive(master, "<some usage>", <other distinguishing information>)
byte[] key2 = Derive(master, "<some usage>", <other distinguishing information>)
byte[] key3 = Derive(master, "<some usage>", <other distinguishing information>)
```

`master` might come from key exchange or key agreement.

`key1`, `key2` and `key3` would be different because because (1) usage is different among invocations, and (2) additional distinguishing information is different among peers.

`Derive` can be a `HMAC` or `CMAC`, and includes the elements of a KDF. Also look at HKDF, which is state of the art for the 'expand then extract' algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed response! 

First the objective: This is to build a system where clients can deterministically (re)generate public key pairs which will be used to exchange data using the existing key pairs. 

The passwords don't have to be in English. Hex keys will be re-entered to regenerate the key pairs when clients wish to exchange data. This is why the passwords are randomly generated in the stub and presented to a registering client. After the initial generation of keys, each client will have some unique identifier associated with a public key and a public salt.

Comment: I understand your point about using derivative methods rather than use separate calls to EVP_BytesToKey (The RAND_bytes call is just for the initial client registration). I will work on a fleshed out test implementation keeping the points you stated in mind and get back. 

That being said, I have been unable to find any good example of creating an RSA keypair (or any other asymmetric key pair) deterministically from a given seed (256 bit random seed, in this case) in OpenSSL for C/C++. It would be immensely useful if you or someone else here could point me to such an example.